# Node addon "Check failed: IsEmpty()"

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api, n-api

I have a Node addon related to a failure, when I destroy an object. I have no idea which object is causing that. Here is some features I am using.

I have a project where I create a few objects using [Napi::ObjectWrap](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/object_wrap.md), some asynchronous functions that do CPU work in using [Napi::AsyncWorker](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/async_worker.md), I also keep a reference to some class definition constructors, using [Napi::Persistent](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/object_reference.md), and calling `constructor.SuppressDestruct`.

This is the error message I receive

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: IsEmpty().
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffc339551c0
 1: 0xb75dd1  [node]
 2: 0x1c08724 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xf24789  [node]
 4: 0xf2f718 v8::internal::ScavengerCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 5: 0xeafa25 v8::internal::Heap::Scavenge() [node]
 6: 0xebe440  [node]
 7: 0xebee20 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xec1d9e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 9: 0xe832da v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
10: 0x11fc026 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
11: 0x15f0a99  [node]
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Reading about [IsEmpty](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/value.md#isempty), I suspected that this could be due to disabling C++ exceptions, my `binding.gyp` file has `-fexceptions` in both `cflags` and `cflags_cc`, and I removed a define `NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS` I was using before, but the behavior stays the same.

I worked around this problem by having a global constant instance. While it worked for my current user case, for more complex cases I would like to create and destroy the objects dynamically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't destroy V8 objects - only the garbage collector can destroy them. You should simply dereference them. Can you post your object creation / object deletion code?

Comment: Sorry, by destroying an object I mean dereferencing it, either by running out of scope, overriding the variable, or explicitly calling delete. Unfortunately I couldn't craft a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you know at least how I could use the Object number to know what the object was?

Comment: From what I understand, there is a certain object that when it is a global instance, does not lead to a crash, and when it is dynamically allocated - it does lead to a crash. Can you post this code?

Comment: It is not open source, but even if I get the permission to post it here, what is the maximum amount of code that would be reasonable for a stack overflow question? Certainly not 2k lines of code, added to that the third party code and libraries, it is about half an hour to build, and if you want to see the error you may have to wait for a script running a few minutes. This is why I preferred to write this in a high level.

Comment: If you can create a toy example and show how to proceed with the investigation of this type of issue, that is is an acceptable answer.

Comment: You are doing something with an object that you are not supposed to.  You can try a full debug build of Node.js/V8 which will give you a little bit more information. It is not very easy to unwrap and print the object in the garbage collector where your crash is - and you probably do not need to go down so deep.
You are not supposed to be deleting `ObjectWrap` objects. Also, you are not supposed to be directly creating them - you should inherit from this class to define your own objects.